# Remove the underlining when inputing into edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

I want to remove the underlining decoration when I am inputting text into my edit text. And something more, is it possible to get rid of this padding or margin that is between the inputted text and the blue border below it?

Right now the edittext looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Try in xml, <EditText height.. weight.. android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" > or programatically  edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `edit_text_background.xml` in your drawables folder with following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>

</shape>
```

Then simply set `android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"` field to the same drawable file.

Answer (score -1):

editText.setBackroundDrawable(null);

Comment: This removed the blue underlining. I wanted that underlining. The one that I dont want is the grey one under the text that is being inputed.